# Are questions about ordering and shipping on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

As the Raspberry Pi is still relatively new, and it still has a way to go when it comes to distribution, I'm fairly certain that a lot of the site's visitors will still have not acquired one. Obviously questions about ordering and pre-ordering and the like will be on their minds. Will those types of questions be allowed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No.

I'd like to see them off-topic. Questions about ordering and shipping aren't really under the control of Raspberry Pi. They are under the various sellers, which we don't have any influence or information about.

Basically, we are here to answer questions about Raspberry Pi, not about Element 14 or Farnell.

Comment: I agree completely there is no way to provide an responsible answer to this question.

Comment: Really? An answer like "You can join the waiting list at A or B retailer buy one. At the time of writing, they currently don't ask for a commitment to buy when joining the list" is completely responsible and extremely useful. If you're really worried, you could remind people to read the small print before signing up.

Comment: Purchasing recommendations towards a specific supplier definitely should be discouraged!

Answer (score 5):

No. Those sort of questions should probably go to the foundation's forum.

Answer (score 1):

They should be closed with a pointer to an FAQ which has links to the web sites of suppliers.

Answer (score -3):

I'd like to see them being considered on-topic, but they may need to be heavily edited into something useful.

Questions that will quickly be out of date or are too localised should still be closed though.